# I need a help to understand WHEN clause

Tags: php, laravel

i'm working on a small project using Laravel and i do my best to understand the Laravel documentation to create a nice solutions, but this time i found some difficult to understand the WHEN clause

can someone explain to me this code by giving me an example:

```
    $role = $request->input('role');

$users = DB::table('users')
                ->when($role, function ($query, $role) {
                    return $query->where('role_id', $role);
                })
                ->get();
```

Docs : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Also i would like to know what stand for the second parameter `[] in the input function`

```
request()->input('field', []);
```

Comment: The docs says: "The when method only executes the given Closure when the first parameter is true. If the first parameter is false, the Closure will not be executed.". This seems to be very clear to me. In this case, if `$role` is evaluated to `true`, the `where` is added to the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the variable role equates to true, this query will execute:

```
return $query->where('role_id', $role);
```

In terms of your second question, if request parameter 'field' is not filled the default value set will be: [].

Another Example:

```
$foo = $request->input('test', 69);
```

If the request parameter test isn't filled, the parameter foo will be 69.